# Dependency Injection on Multitenant Applications

Tags: entity-framework-4, multi-tenant

I've been doing some research on DI (Unity and Ninject) for a multi-tenant ASP.Net MVC 4 application. Most articles I've read seem to refer to DI as a good tool to help provide customizations to the tenants in a multu-tenant web application. Other than that what else is it useful for within the Multitenant world.

Can it help with data isolation in share db schema scenario? I'm trying to find a clean way to isolate data between customers. (I'm using tenantId in all tables where needed)

(ASP.Net MVC4, Entity Framework 5, SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, as far as the data isolation is concerned in a multi-tenant application using a shared schema, I don't foresee any use of a DI Container as it just helps resolve object dependencies. It is up to you to have the security control mechanisms and tenant isolation practices in your application that filters the data based on the operating tenant or the contextual tenant.

You have to carry forward the tenant identifier from the presentation tier throughout the other layers till the data base access. It is in the access logic where you will be filtering the data based on the tenant, this can be done using the tenant identifier in the tables.

Also, in a single code base approach there will be no requirement for injecting dependencies to identify tenant. The tenant identification and validation the operating user and his tenant context will be done by your application during authentication and authorization phase itself.

Hope this addresses your query